# web3.eth.subscribe give response blank

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I am using web3 1.0.0 on **nodejs** all working fine but **web3.eth.subscribe** not working for **pendingTransactions**,  I don't understand what is the issue.

I'm using
web3 version : 1.0.0
OS : windows
provider : IpcProvider

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider("\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc", require("net")));

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.IpcProvider("\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc", require("net")));

var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function(error, result){
if (!error)
    console.log(result);
else
    console.log(error);
})
.on("data", function(transaction){
    console.log(transaction);
});
```

Run this code on nodejs and i got the response blank

Comment: Just a hunch, but are you connecting through an HttpProvider?

Comment: i am using IPCProvider

`web3.providers.IpcProvider('\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc',net)`